# ことに(と)なった indicates reason/cause?

Tags: sentence

時計の数字から影が漏れ出た瞬間、狂三の左目の時計が恐ろしい速さで正方向に回った気がしたのである。
だが、その疑問は、すぐ頭の中から追い出される**ことになった**。
「な......」
真那の怪訝そうな声が、士道の耳に届く。この位置からでは真那の表情は窺い知れないが、恐らく士道と似たような顔を作っているに違いなかった。
狂三が、左手に握った短銃の銃口を、自分のあごに押し当てたのである。
「一体何をーー」
真那の言葉の途中で、狂三はニヤリと笑うと、何も躊躇うことなく引き金を引いた。
ドン！という音が辺りに響き、狂三の頭部がぐわんと揺れる。どう見ても、自殺したとしか思えない光景だった。
だが。士道と真那は一瞬あと、その感想を強制的に訂正させられる**こととなった**。

Hi. Do the two bold parts indicate cause/reason? Are they the same usage as the ことになった in this sentence そんなことをしたから二度と人前に出られない**ことになった**。? It’s just that the reason or cause is implied in the context in question.
1) is like “because of some reason, it caused the situation ‘this question was quickly driven out of his head’.”
2) is like “because of some reason, it caused the situation ‘Shidou and Mana immediately corrected their way of thinking’.”

Am I on the right track?
If not, how should I understand the two ことになった?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 examples of ことに（と）なった have the same function. However it doesn't indicate the reason/cause in these cases.

Let's take the first example.

> 疑問は頭の中から追い出された
>
> This question was driven out of his head.
>
> 疑問は頭の中から追い出されることになった
>
> The thing that this question was driven out of his head happened.

こと originally means "thing", なる originally means "become", and "ことに(と)なる" means "it happens" something like that.

As you may noticed, "ことに(と)なる" has a function to describe the situation from the neutral viewpoint. It's working like a narration or stuff like that. This is frequently seen in reading text but not so common in colloquial conversation.

> この失敗が後に成功をよぶ**ことになる**とは、このとき誰も知るよしもなかった
>
> No one would known at that moment if this failure could make success later.

In this example, ことになる works as to happen later, which leads a meaning like "destiny". As you said I think it has the reason/cause meaning in this case.

Similarly,

> あとで後悔することになるよ
>
> I'm sure that you're going to regret.

It's saying like "Something will cause the destiny that you're to regret."